# How to publish reply back to reply queue specified as replyTo header with Jms.inboundGateway

Tags: spring-integration

I am using

```
MessageProducerSupport messageProducer =
                Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter(jmsConnectionFactory, TransactedMessageListenerContainer.class)
                        .destination(queue)
                        .get();
```

to consume messages from ActiveMQ queue.

This is first part of my `IntegrationFlow` and then multiple stages occur (transform, route, handle..) within transaction
It is there to handle messages from upstream

In order to get the ACK from Spring integration pipeline I used `Jms.inboundGateway(jmsConnectionFactory, TransactedMessageListenerContainer.class)` which doesn't break existing flow and everything works

When I set `replyTo` header of upstream message, I would assume Spring Integration would send the object of the last stage of `IntegrationFlow` which was successful back to `replyTo` queue

Is my approach correct?
Is it possible to achieve such use-case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's correct and should work by its (Messaging Gateway) premise.

The `Jms.inboundGateway()` is based on the `ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener` with the `expectReply = true` and there is a code:

```
private Destination getReplyDestination(javax.jms.Message request, Session session) throws JMSException {
    Destination replyTo = request.getJMSReplyTo();
    ....
    return replyTo;
}
```

to obtain a `replyTo` from the request.

Everything that works well, if your last `MessageHandler` in the flow is a `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler` and really returns something to be produced to the `replyChannel` from headers.

If you aren't sure in your case, so share the end of your flow and the place where would you like to send a reply.

Comment: Hi Artem, yes, indeed, if I put `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler` at the end of the flow, reply is sent back. The problem is that when incoming message stops, e.g. on the filter, the ACK won't be sent back to replyTo queue. To get you into context why I want to achieve this, I want to load test the application using gatling: http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/jms.html#example

Comment: Well. That's why I'm asking. You should have last `.handle()` with some valuable `return`. And that will become a reply to the JMS. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference#basics

Comment: Is it possible to put something additional after last `handle()`, e.g. `transform` & `channel`
My current setup is 3 `IntegrationFlow`s and 2 JMS queues in between.
So I'd like to send reply to the JMS everytime it is possible, i.e. at the end of each flow.

Comment: Yes, you can, there is just enough to finish your flow with something that returns non-null value. You should bear in mind if your `.handle()` returns nothing or `null` you can't continue the flow. Consider the normal Java program when you wait on the `CountDownLatch`, but nobody is going to countDown it. That is how request-reply in messaging works.

Comment: Got it! I am gonna experiment with it. Thanks for the help!